# Stacked Bar Plot-Starting with NonNumerical Items

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a stacked bar graph to show how the launch vehicles of satellites has changed over time. I'd like the x axis to be the year of the launch, and y axis to be the number of satellites launched on the vehicle, where each section of the bar is a different color that represents the launch vehicle. I am struggling to come up with a way to do this because my Launch Vehicle column is non-numerical. I looked into the group by function as well as  value_counts but can't seem to get it to do what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: You should provide the code with which someone can replicate your dataframe. Anyway the answer should be `pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Year of Launch', 'Launch Vehicle']).agg({'Launch Vehicle':'count'}).reset_index())` . That will give you the grouped dataframe you need to create your plots.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reorganize your data to use `DataFrame.plot` in desired way:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Launch Vehicle':["Soyuz 2.1a",'Ariane 5 ECA','Falcon 9','Long March','Falcon 9', 'Atlas 3','Atlas 3'],
 'Year of Launch': [2016,2014,2016,1997,2015,2004,2004]})

# make groupby by year and rocket type to get the pivot table
# fillna put zero launch if there is no start of such type during the year
df2 = df.groupby(['Year of Launch','Launch Vehicle'])['Year of Launch'].count().unstack('Launch Vehicle').fillna(0)
print(df2)

# plot the data
df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Output of df2:

```
Launch Vehicle  Ariane 5 ECA  Atlas 3  Falcon 9  Long March  Soyuz 2.1a
Year of Launch                                                         
1997                     0.0      0.0       0.0         1.0         0.0
2004                     0.0      2.0       0.0         0.0         0.0
2014                     1.0      0.0       0.0         0.0         0.0
2015                     0.0      0.0       1.0         0.0         0.0
2016                     0.0      0.0       1.0         0.0         1.0
```